# Given The Genratrix ,Maximise Volume Of Cone

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

**source of the problem:**

V.govrov,Pdybov,Nmiroshin,S misirnova PROBLEM IN MATHEMATICS section $2.2 $question number $124$

**question**

Find greatest volume $V$ of the cone with generatrix $a$

**my doubt :**

i don't know how $a$ is related to genratrix .  ( on wiki i found- generatrix or generator is a point, curve or surface that, when moved along a given path, generates a new shape  ).but i'm confused about if it is slant height of the cone or it's radius ?

any help is appreciated

Comment: I would say that the cone generatrix is a line of length 'a' intersecting the cone axis (lateral, conic height of the cone, or  of the "double cone").

Comment: @georg : okay do you mean it's slant height of cone